Splitting points into 6 equal sets with three lines
Given a set of $6k=n$ points in general position in $\mathbb{R}^2$, prove we can split them into six sets of $k$ points each using three concurrent lines.
I figured out how to do this for the area of a polygon with intermediate value theorem but don't know how to deal with the instances when two points would accidentally end up on one of the lines, so there's no way to apply pseudo-intermediate value theorem.

When you say "three intersecting lines", do you mean the three intersect each other in a single point? If not, then three mutually intersecting lines divide the plane into $7$ regions, not $6$.

I've noticed the first line has to split the set in two equal halves, which one can always do, but the next two lines are a bit trickier.

@PaulSinclair Yes, should've specified. They should be mutually intersecting.

Does your area division solution still work when you have a density function, and the object is to divide the mass into 6 equal parts? If so, you can examine the limiting case as you concentrate the mass more and more at the points. This will give a "solution" possibly with lines passing through the points. Then examine whether the discreteness gives you wiggle room to move the lines off the points.
